# How can I find the amount of pixels in part of an image?

Tags: photoshop, photo, gimp

I have an image and I want to see how many pixels are in different parts of the image. Is there a software I can use to do this?

Comment: How many pixels? That is width*height, I believe you might be asking about something else.

Comment: Please show an example so we can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

In Gimp, the ["Histogram" dialog](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-histogram-dialog.html) applies to the selection, so the pixel count displayed is the pixels in the selection (weighted by their selection level):

In the image below the selection covers the black circle which has a 100px radius. The `Pixels` value is close to 100²*Pi (314000 instead of 314159).

[image]

The  `Count` is the number of pixels between the two values indicated by the handles at the bottom of the histogram.

Of course the selection can have any shape and be obtained with various tools.

I assume PS has something equivalent.